# What is the physical meaning of two solutions of grating solutions for $m=0$?

Tags: optics, diffraction

[image]

I was confused by how Feynman defined the angle of input and output. I thought it is regular reflection when input angle equals output angle where it is the first situation in Feynman’s description. And the second is the transmissive grating.

[image]

Here is regular grating equation. When $m=0$, one of solutions is regular reflection like a mirror, the incident angle equal to output angle. I want to know what the other solution means that the output angle is supplement of incident angle, this is also a solution for $m=0$.

Comment: The light is transmitted?

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions are $\varphi_0 = -\theta_i$ and $\varphi_0 =180^\circ + \theta_i$. One of these corresponds to the law of reflection as you indicate, and the other corresponds to transmission with no deflection (which is which depends on how you define $\varphi_m$). Naturally, the latter only makes sense for a transmissive grating (one that lets light through).

Comment: Ok, cool, thank you. So, the light from source can go through the grating with the same direction as before . And meantime it drives the electrons in grating oscillate and generate a new light in same direction and as a result it can interfere with the light from the source, is this right?

Comment: @XiangLi The angles $\varphi_m$ are the angles at which the waves (re)radiated by different parts of the grating constructively interfere with *themselves*. It probably isn't accurate to speak of them as interfering with the light from the source. For instance when we are talking about a transmitted diffraction peak, how do we even separate the light from the source and the light "from the grating"? Ultimately it all comes from the grating.

Comment: I actually was confused by the book on Feynman physics. I edited the question and hope it is clear. I also got the inference idea from Feynman.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. While Feynman's diagram could be clearer, $\theta_{in}$ is the angle of incidence and $\theta_{out}$ is the angle between the outgoing beam and the normal vector, what you would call the angle of reflection. The case $\theta_{out} = \theta_{in}$ corresponds to reflection, and $\theta_{out} = 180^\circ - \theta_{in}$ is transmission without deflection (in the original direction of the incident beam).

Comment: In his description, when theta_out is supplement of theta_in, that is theta_out = 180- theta_in, I thought this situation is transmission but he said this situation was reflection. And when the two angles equal it transmits in the same direction as the incident light.

Comment: I see. The figure is misleading in this case, I think he really has a different picture in mind when he writes this, I was going by the figure (not the text) in my previous comment. He is talking about a transmissive grating, and the figure should really show the outgoing beams as being transmitted rather than reflected. If you draw the figure accordingly (i.e. "flip" the reflected beams so they are now being transmitted), and define $\theta_{out}$ as the angle between the outgoing beam and the (downward) normal vector, it will match up with his description in the text.

Comment: Ok, it’s clear now, thank you so much.